# How far can snails see?

Tags: snails

I have many problems with snails and slugs in my garden. When I want to plant something I usually grow it far away enough from the garden until the plant is big enough to support some "attacks".

I was quite surprised today when I found 2 slugs and one snail in a plant, around 4 meters away from the garden (grass and other plants) and that is actually hanging in a wall support. I don't think they came with the plant so they had to spot it from the garden, walk 4 meters in pavement, risking their lifes, climb the wall, and then down the support.

This makes me think that I should reassess where I make my seed plot place and makes me wonder how far can they see or how do they find plants like this?

Comment: Here's an interesting article, although it doesn't expressly answer your question: http://animals.mom.me/snails-eyes-10446.html

Comment: Note that they also have olfactory (i.e. smelling) organs ([rhinophores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhinophore)).

Comment: @dakab Your comment looks to me like the makings of a valid answer, as the last part of the question asks how, other than seeing, do they find plants. If you want to write it, I think it would be helpful and on-topic.

Comment: @Sue: Thank you for encouraging me. I’d really love to give an appropriate answer. Unfortunately—as a non-native speaker—I don’t feel like I’m up to it. Not if it’s ought to satisfy a minimal (layman’s) scientific standard. However, there’s an extensive article on the **[sensory organs of gastropods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensory_organs_of_gastropods)**.

Comment: @dakab yes I understand... but the question remains. How far can they smell. And can they smell directionaly?. It's quite amazing they ended up there.

Comment: Thinking scientifically, maybe 2 slugs and a snail out of the entire population of them got lucky when they found your garden. They probably don't walk down the street, spot something across the road and have a look. Its more likely that all the snail graze all over an area and some end up in gardens.

Comment: Also, slugs seen to prefer beer to plants in my experience, so perhaps leaving a trap out for them is better than relocating your seed plot.

Comment: @Nic I understand your point and you're probably right. Regarding beer, I tried making traps and got one or two slugs a day - Which is very low given the amount I have in plants. I gave up on that when I realized that the slugs were actually drinking more than me :)

Answer (score 3):

[A page about snail vision](http://www.molluscs.at/gastropoda/index.html?/gastropoda/morphology/eyes.html).

- They have better eyesight than other animals in their group.
- They can avoid larger obstacles.
- They can't focus they eye.

> Vision is not the most important requirement in terrestrial gastropods, because they are mainly nocturnal animals. 
>   [From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensory_organs_of_gastropods).

Comment: Nocturnal and already there hiding till they come out at night. Put a wide board down with a little gap underneath, turn it over after a couple days. It will tell you what kind of slug/snail population you already have before planting.